# setup log4j2 file appender programmatically

Tags: java, log4j2

I've been trying to build a Java application utilizing log4j v2.7.  I have some command line arguments which allow the user to configure log4j so I'm trying to configure it programmatically.

Here's the function (mostly copied from log4j documentation)

```
public static void configureLogging(String path) {
    ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();
    LayoutComponentBuilder layoutBuilder = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable");

    builder.setStatusLevel(Level.ALL);
    builder.setConfigurationName("BuilderTest");
    AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("Stdout", "CONSOLE")
            .addAttribute("target", ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
    appenderBuilder.add(layoutBuilder);

    builder.add(appenderBuilder);
    builder.add(builder.newLogger("Console", Level.ALL).add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout")));

    appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("file_log", "File")
        .addAttribute("fileName", path)
        .addAttribute("append", false)
        .add(layoutBuilder);
    builder.add(appenderBuilder);

    builder.add(builder.newRootLogger(Level.ALL).add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout")));
    builder.add( builder.newRootLogger( Level.ALL ).add( builder.newAppenderRef("file_log")));

    Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
}
```

So the console outputs as expected.  And an empty log file gets created but it doesn't output anything to the file.

Comment: Do you know that [log4j2 can automatically reconfigure itself](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticReconfiguration) when there are changes to the config file? You could externalize the configuration file and then your code doesn't depend on the implementation details of log4j2, which makes it easier to maintain in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are creating `RootLogger` instance 2 times in below lines -

```
builder.add(builder.newRootLogger(Level.ALL).add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout")));
builder.add( builder.newRootLogger( Level.ALL ).add( builder.newAppenderRef("file_log")));
```

Try below line in place of above 2 lines -

```
builder.add(builder.newRootLogger(Level.ALL).add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout")).add(builder.newAppenderRef("file_log")));
```